# Acer Veriton Z290G display distorted in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, widescreen

I am running Windows 7 on the Acer Veriton Z290G. I successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04. The only problem I have is that the display is stretched out horizontally, so much that a small portion of the left and right of the display is beyond the edge of the screen. Xrandr returns [LVDS1 connected 1024x768 60.0]
[VGA1 connected 1366x768 59.8 +].
I only have one monitor, the built-in, and it is LCD (LVDS) with 1366x768 resolution. How do I get Ubuntu to recognize the correct resolution? When I tried newmode and addmode, it just adjusts the VGA settings, which is no help. Anybody have a solution that a nube like myself can understand?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, after getting some input. Turns out I needed to switch to VGA mode from terminal:
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768